# object of type 'NoneType' has no len() Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been experimenting with dicts in python so I can remove 'magic numbers' as I think they are referred to but I keep getting the error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len(). It only happens some of the time in my hangman program, and I am unsure why. This is the general area where I think it crashes:

```
animals = 'ape bear beaver cat donkey fox goat llama monkey python bunny tiger wolf'.split()
colors = 'yellow red blue green orange purple pink brown black white gold'.split()
adjectives = 'happy sad lonely cold hot ugly pretty thin fat big small tall short'.split()
names = {'animals': animals, 'colors': colors, 'adjectives': adjectives}
categories = [names['animals'],names['colors'],names['adjectives']]

def getRandomWord(wordList):
    wordList = random.choice(list(names.keys())) 
    wordIndex = random.randint(0,len(wordList))
    print(animals[wordIndex])

    if(random.choice(list(names.keys())) == 'animals'):
        print("The category is animals!")
        return animals[wordIndex]
    if(random.choice(list(names.keys())) == 'colors'):
        print("The category is colors!")
        return colors[wordIndex]    
    if(random.choice(list(names.keys())) == 'adjectives'):
        print("The category is adjectives!")
        return adjectives[wordIndex]
```

What should I do to fix my problem?

Comment: Unless you are changing `names` to something else (reassignment) elsewhere in your program, then this is not the issue.  Also, not that `list(dict.keys())` is redundant as `keys()` returns a list already.

Comment: You have 13 animals, 11 colors, and 13 adjectives. Did you mean for the lists to all be the same length?

Comment: You should give us more context, better explain what you are trying to achieve, and paste the backtrace. I can make no sense out of this code.

Comment: @sberry: It might be Python 3, in which case you'd want `list(names)`. It's unfortunately impossible to tell whether those are print functions or confusingly-parenthesized print statements.

Comment: @user2357112: ah, right.  Still py2.7 here so I have not run into that yet.

Comment: Why do you take a `wordList` argument and then immediately throw it away?

Answer (score 3):

Right now, you're drawing a different category three times.  The first time you compare it to `'animals'`; the second to `'colors'`; and the third to `'adjectives'`.

But what if you drew `'colors'` and then `'animals'` and then `'colors'` again?  None of your three "if" branches will trigger.  Since there's no `return` which is executed, there's an effective `return None` at the end.

Alternatively, if your `names` isn't what you think it is, you could be drawing a `None` value, I guess: you didn't show the whole stacktrace, so I'm guessing about where the error manifests.

(Also, your `wordIndex` could possibly be set to `len(wordList)`, which would result in an IndexError because the last index is `len(wordList)-1`.  Moreover, since the `wordIndex` didn't necessarily come from the list associated with the category, you could have indexing errors there too.)

I think you can simplify your code to something like:

```
import random
animals = 'ape bear beaver cat donkey fox goat llama monkey python bunny tiger wolf'.split()
colors = 'yellow red blue green orange purple pink brown black white gold'.split()
adjectives = 'happy sad lonely cold hot ugly pretty thin fat big small tall short'.split()
names = {'animals': animals, 'colors': colors, 'adjectives': adjectives}

def getRandomWord(words_by_category):
    category = random.choice(list(words_by_category.keys()))
    print("the category is", category)
    wordlist = words_by_category[category]
    chosen_word = random.choice(wordlist)
    return chosen_word
```

after which we have:

```
>>> getRandomWord(names)
the category is colors
'blue'
>>> getRandomWord(names)
the category is adjectives
'happy'
>>> getRandomWord(names)
the category is colors
'green'
>>> getRandomWord(names)
the category is animals
'donkey'
```